# How to get certain entries from python xrange - django paginator

Tags: python, django

I am using Django paginator and am trying to get it do display multiple pages at the bottom. Currently I am setting it up so that it will only display a few numbers around your current number (e.g. next 2 3 **4** 5 6 prev), I know how I am going to do this however I am struggling with how django's pagination stores the page_range. It stores it as an x_range and because of this I dont know how to get certain values out of it.

```
middle = job_listings.paginator.page_range[before:after]
```

That is what I am trying to do however it returns the following error. Could anyone tell me how to get a range of items out of an xrange?

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/browse?page=4

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'main',
 'listings',
 'profiles',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Other folders\Desktop\Student Job Search\code\opus_jobs_project\listings\views.py" in browse
  54.     middle = job_listings.paginator.page_range[before:after]

Exception Type: TypeError at /listings/browse
Exception Value: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

Potentially relevant pagination code -

```
job_listings_list = JobListing.objects.filter(filters).distinct().order_by('-listing_date')
print(job_listings_list)

paginator = Paginator(job_listings_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    job_listings = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    job_listings = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    job_listings = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

current_page_start = job_listings.start_index()
current_page_end = job_listings.end_index()

before_current_pages=1
after_current_pages=1
before = max(job_listings.number - before_current_pages, 0)
after = job_listings.number + after_current_pages
middle = job_listings.paginator.page_range[before:after]
print("before", before, "after", after)
```

(Let me know if you need any more code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an xrange object as a list by calling list on it.

```
>>> x = xrange(5)
>>> x
xrange(5)
>>> list(x)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```